# How to validate URLs and exclude certain domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model to store URLs but I want to exclude some specified domains, e.g: http://google.com. Here is the model:

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :url, presence: true
  validates :url, format: { with: /\Ahttps?:\/\//,
                            without: Regexp.new("http://google.com") }
end
```

But I got this error messages:

```
Either :with or :without must be supplied (but not both)
```

How to write the validation for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can separate it into two validates

```
validates :url, format: { with: /\Ahttps?:\/\//}
validates :url, format: { without: Regexp.new("http://google.com") }
```

Comment: LOL why didn't I think of that before

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
validates :url, format: { with: /\Ahttps?:\/\//}
validates :url, exclusion: { in: %w(google) }
```